# Google clooud vision API is giving error on restriction in android

Tags: android, api, vision

{
"code": 403,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"message": "Requests from this Android client application  are blocked.",
"reason": "forbidden"
}
],
"message": "Requests from this Android client application  are blocked.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}

Comment: Please share your code and all the necessary logs in your question. It is pretty insufficient as its current state.

Comment: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}

@EfeBudak

Comment: be sure to give permission to your client from the google cloud developer console. It looks like it is the issue in your case.